# sql select and compare most recent and nth most recent value but exclude when value has been repeated for more than three months

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the following query to select the most recent and 3rd most recent values from a table grouped by their MeterNumber. The user supplies a month and day which determines the highest value returned.

The purpose of the query is to look at the Water Reads for a Meter and see if they are the same over a 3 month period. If so no consumption is happening and the meter is likely broken.

My problem is that I'd also like to exclude any meter's that have had the same read for the 4th, 5th, 6th, ... most recent read dates because these meters are likely unused.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm very new to this so perhaps there is a much more efficient/better way to accomplish this.

I'm using MS SQL 2012.

```
SELECT 
MeterNumber, 
MAX(WaterRead) AS CurrentRead, 
MAX(ReadDate) AS CurrentReadDate, 
MIN(WaterRead) AS nthLastRead, 
MIN(ReadDate) AS nthLastReadDate
From
(SELECT MeterNumber, ReadDate, WaterRead
    FROM (
        SELECT MeterNumber, ReadDate, WaterRead, Rank() over (Partition BY MeterNumber ORDER BY ReadDate DESC ) AS myRank
    FROM WaterReads
) WaterReads WHERE myRank <= 3 ) a
Group By MeterNumber
Having MAX(WaterRead) - MIN(WaterRead) = 0 AND MAX(WaterRead) != 0 AND MIN(WaterRead) != 0     AND MIN(ReadDate) <> MAX(ReadDate)
AND MONTH(MAX(ReadDate)) = 6 AND DAY(MAX(ReadDate)) = 25
ORDER BY MeterNumber, CurrentReadDate
```

This returns:

```
MeterNumber CurrentRead CurrentReadDate nthLastRead nthLastReadDate
80021139    12103       2013-06-25      12103   2013-04-24
80029512    5347        2013-06-25      5347    2013-04-24
80038245    304304      2013-06-25      304304  2013-04-24
80044119    46250       2013-06-25      46250   2013-04-24
80048357    6707        2013-06-25      6707    2013-04-24
```

Comment: So you want to display results if the current read equals the third-previous read, but *not* if it equals the sixth-previous read?

Comment: @Joe - yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.  You can use max(case when...) to pluck out the specific previous periods to compare.  Like so:

```
SELECT
    meternumber,
    MAX(CASE WHEN myrank = 1 THEN readdate ELSE NULL END) curr_date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN myrank = 1 THEN waterread ELSE NULL END) curr_read,
    MAX(CASE WHEN myrank = 4 THEN readdate ELSE NULL END) ago3_date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN myrank = 4 THEN waterread ELSE NULL END) ago3_read,
    MAX(CASE WHEN myrank = 7 THEN readdate ELSE NULL END) ago6_date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN myrank = 7 THEN waterread ELSE NULL END) ago6_read
FROM
(        
    SELECT  MeterNumber, 
            ReadDate, 
            WaterRead, 
            Rank() over (Partition BY MeterNumber ORDER BY ReadDate DESC ) AS myRank
      FROM  WaterReads
            WHERE   readdate <= '20130625'
) AS a
GROUP BY
    meternumber
HAVING
    MAX(CASE WHEN myrank = 1 THEN waterread ELSE NULL END) = MAX(CASE WHEN myrank = 4 THEN waterread ELSE NULL END) 
    AND MAX(CASE WHEN myrank = 1 THEN waterread ELSE NULL END) > MAX(CASE WHEN myrank = 7 THEN waterread ELSE NULL END) 
    AND MAX(CASE WHEN myrank = 4 THEN waterread ELSE NULL END) > 0
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80f8b/1/0)

Or, a little easier to read, but with an additional subquery:

```
SELECT
    meternumber,
    curr_date,
    curr_read,
    ago3_date,
    ago3_read,
    ago6_date,
    ago6_read
FROM    
(
    SELECT
        meternumber,
        MAX(CASE WHEN myrank = 1 THEN readdate ELSE NULL END) curr_date,
        MAX(CASE WHEN myrank = 1 THEN waterread ELSE NULL END) curr_read,
        MAX(CASE WHEN myrank = 4 THEN readdate ELSE NULL END) ago3_date,
        MAX(CASE WHEN myrank = 4 THEN waterread ELSE NULL END) ago3_read,
        MAX(CASE WHEN myrank = 7 THEN readdate ELSE NULL END) ago6_date,
        MAX(CASE WHEN myrank = 7 THEN waterread ELSE NULL END) ago6_read
    FROM
    (        
        SELECT  MeterNumber, 
                ReadDate, 
                WaterRead, 
                Rank() over (Partition BY MeterNumber ORDER BY ReadDate DESC ) AS myRank
          FROM  WaterReads
                WHERE   readdate <= '20130625'
    ) AS a
    GROUP BY
        meternumber
) AS b
WHERE
    curr_read = ago3_read
    AND curr_read > ago6_read
    AND ago3_read > 0
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful and works for what i'm trying to do. I appreciate that you provided a fiddle as well as a second version for me to understand!